# Tensorflow: How to write clean code for multi GPU model parallelism?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Currently i'm implementing a large custom model and referencing the multi gpu example of CIFAR 10 that comes along with tensorflow. However the code I ended up writing based on that was not clean and was error prone. For e.g. I had to find every trainable variable and add "with tf.device('/cpu:0')".

Are there more efficient/cleaner ways of adapting for multi gpu execution?

Many thanks for any support.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [example](https://github.com/rafaljozefowicz/lm/blob/master/language_model.py) from Rafal

You make a loop over towers with the body constructing `i`th tower as `with tf.device(assign_to_gpu(i))`. The function `assign_to_gpu` treats variables differently and assigns them onto "ps-device".

Note: we found that when GPUs are p2p connected, training was faster when variables were kept `gpu:0` rather than `cpu:0`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I will try this out. Wondering if there is something similar to [Transparent multi gpu training with Keras/TF](https://medium.com/@kuza55/transparent-multi-gpu-training-on-tensorflow-with-keras-8b0016fd9012#.zfmr798wv)